# Spring Batch : Parse one comma separated line with thousands of tokens

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have an input file as mentioned below.

```
TOKEN1,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2,TOKEN2
```

This sample data is one line with tokens separated by comma.

I want to know which Mapper will work for such kind of data?

Thanks

Comment: What are the relationship between the tokens?  Is it just a list of independent values?

Comment: @JustinKSU.... Yes tokens are independent

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DelimitedLineTokenizer. The list of tokens will be supplied to the ItemProcessor. I've shown a code snippet below.

If each of the tokens corresponds to a field in an entity you can also set a BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper which will parse each line and create an object of that entity automatically.

```
    public FlatFileItemReader<Feature> reader(String pathToFile, ApplicationContext ctx) {
    FlatFileItemReader<Feature> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Feature>();
    Resource path = ctx.getResource("file:" + pathToFile);
    reader.setResource(path);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Feature>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(
                    DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_COMMA) {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] {"token1", "token2", "token3", .... , "tokenx" });
                }
            });
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}
```

Comment: You are missing `LineMapper.fieldSetMapper` mandatory property. In addiction the token list is not sent to `ItemProcessor` directly because it need to be mapped using `LineMapper.fieldSetMapper`. Use a `PassThroughFieldSetMapper` or `ArrayFieldSetMapper` to pass raw data to `ItemProcessor`

Comment: I forgot about the fieldSetMapper. Thank you.